# Getting unknown integer in javascript nested loop

Tags: javascript, nested-loops

I am totally new to JavaScript. learning on codecademy.
I am trying this code but output is adding "1" before every element of array.

```
    // Write your code below
const bobsFollowers = ['John', 'Eric', 'Naleen', 'Ajeet'];
const tinasFollowers = ['Eric', 'Naleen', 'Athira'];
const mutualFollowers = [''];
for (let i = 0; i < bobsFollowers.length; i++){
  for (let j = 0; j < tinasFollowers.length; j++){
    if (bobsFollowers[i] === tinasFollowers[j]) {
        console.log(mutualFollowers.push() + tinasFollowers[j])
    }
    
  }
}
```

Comment: The reason you were getting a 1 before the output is that you were actually logging a string made up of the return value of `push()` and the name returned by `tinasFollowers[j]`

Answer (score 1):

Ciao, your error is on `push`. Try to add directly `tinasFollowers[j]` to `mutualFollowers`  and initialize `mutualFollowers` to `[]`.

Here an example:

```js
const bobsFollowers = ['John', 'Eric', 'Naleen', 'Ajeet'];
const tinasFollowers = ['Eric', 'Naleen', 'Athira'];
const mutualFollowers = [];
for (let i = 0; i < bobsFollowers.length; i++){
  for (let j = 0; j < tinasFollowers.length; j++){
    if (bobsFollowers[i] === tinasFollowers[j]) {
        mutualFollowers.push(tinasFollowers[j])
    }
    
  }
}
console.log(mutualFollowers)
```

Comment: Ciao, your solution returns 1 because function `push` returns the new length of the array. But as I said, you didn't push anything in `mutualFollowers` array (because you wrote `mutualFollowers.push()`). So when you log `mutualFollowers.push()`, `push` function returns the actual length of `mutualFollowers` array (that is 1 because you initalized it to `['']` and `''` is the only element you have in `mutualFollowers` array).

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Giovanni's answer, especially in light of you just learning array iteration, but will post this for reference using `Array.filter()` and `Array.includes()` introduced in ECMAScript 6.

```js
const bobsFollowers = ['John', 'Eric', 'Naleen', 'Ajeet'];
const tinasFollowers = ['Eric', 'Naleen', 'Athira'];

const mutualFollowers = bobsFollowers.filter((name) => tinasFollowers.includes(name));

console.log(mutualFollowers);
// ["Eric", "Naleen"]
```

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way is to use the built-in Array.prototype.includes() and Array.prototype.reduce()

```
const bob = ['Jane', 'Larry', 'Fred'];
const anne = ['Larry', 'Fred', 'Moe'];

const common = bob.reduce((acc, friend) => anne.includes(friend) ? [...acc, friend] : acc, []);

console.log(common);
```